# enable/disable option in MultipleSelect

Tags: javascript

I'm using MultipleSelect as it is a good option for the inconvenient handling of multiple options in a normal select. Due to optical reasons i'm using it also for normal single selects.

The problem is now, that it's converting a select into a list of radio buttons. In my case i have an option in a select, that must be enabled by a separate checkbox. When i address it to the normal select, the option is enabled, but not the radio in the list. But these options also don't have an id, so that I could change the radio directly.

This is the code that is generated for the select. The second option is disabled and should be enabled.

```
<div class="ms-parent multiple-select" title="" style="width: 300px;">
<button type="button" class="ms-choice">
    <div class="icon-caret open"></div>
</button>
<div class="ms-drop bottom" style="display: block;">
    <ul style="max-height: 250px;">
        <li class=" hide-radio ">
            <label class="">
                <input type="radio" value="" data-key="option_0" data-name="selectItemstatus">
                <span>status red</span>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li class=" hide-radio ">
            <label class="disabled">
                <input type="radio" value="105" data-key="option_1" data-name="selectItemstatus" disabled="disabled">
                <span>status green</span>
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In the documentation i only found how to enable/disable a complete select, but not a single option. Anybody have an idea how to enable the radio button?

Comment: Just disable the `option` element on the original `select` element, and then just use the `refresh` method, http://multiple-select.wenzhixin.net.cn/examples#refresh.html …?

Comment: Didn't expect to be so easy. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just disable the `option` on the original `select` element - and then use the `refresh` method.

Details on usage can be found here,
http://multiple-select.wenzhixin.net.cn/examples#refresh.html
http://multiple-select.wenzhixin.net.cn/docs/en/methods#refresh